# NetworkManager 1.10.2 segfaults when shorewall starts

Tags: networkmanager, segmentation-fault

I am trying to debug an issue that happens all the time.  NetworkManager is running and upon connecting to a network, I am using a dispatcher script to setup my firewall rules (shorewall, and it is set to run asynchronously).  As soon as shorewall sets up the rules, NetworkManager crashes:

```
NetworkManager segfault at 8 ip 00007fa89e102e16 sp 00007fff51f34be8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fa89e084000+18e000]
```

I don't understand why shorewall / iptables would have a direct impact here.  I tried cutting back my ruleset from shorewall and it still crashes.  Lastly, I disabled shorewall altogether and went with a very plain iptables script, and that worked without issue.  Shorewall is also configuring QOS, so there are other things going on, but I still am having a tough time believing that there could be a direct link.

Also, if I revert back to an older version of NetworkManager 1.4.4-r1, I don't have any issues.  Lastly, I also manually reverted back to the prior working version of shorewall while keeping NetworkManager at 1.10.2 and that had no impact.  So, I don't believe it is an issue with shorewall, but instead something NetworkManager is doing differently.

I tried to use strace here, but I'm not making heads or tails out of the output.

What else can I do to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted back to NetworkManager 1.4.4-r1 and the problem appears to go away.  I will file a bug report with NetworkManager.